# How to intercept C++ standard library functions with dynamic linker API (dlsym())

Tags: c++, c++11, fork, cout, io-redirection

Is there a way one can go about intercepting the standard C++ library functions like the `operator<<()` functions?  I was thinking of somehow using the `dlsym()` function to achieve this..  I doubt a portable solution would exist because C++ compilers do a lot of name mangling with symbols, especially since `cout` is in the namespace `std`.  But I am not very sure.

I would like to do this because I am redirecting stdout to another file descriptor and since people do not usually check when `operator<<` with `cout` fails I want to put in an assertion to see if a write failed when a client calls `operator<<` with `cout`.  I would just do this for the write function but I do not know for sure whether operator<< calls write..  In the past I had assumed similarly that new would call malloc but I was proven wrong.

This would be a very useful thing in my opinion for "meta" programs and therefore I do not want to limit myself to just `operator<<()` with `cout`.  If there is any way to intercept C++ standard library functions I would love to know!

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem most probably wouldn't be name mangling, but inlining. Anyway, to achieve your objective it may be enough to enable the exceptions over `cout` (see [`std::ios::exceptions`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/)).

Comment: +1 I did not know that existed!  Also will calling exec mess up this sort of a setup?  I am not sure whether exec invokes another dynamic linking to occur.

Comment: It's possible, and commonly done in embedded development. You should provide your own implementation of the standard library functions. In gcc, that's equivalent to re-implementing  libstdc++.

Comment: @xvan Not really.  I am just talking about intercepting the function call.  Not implementing the functions again.  Check out http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym

Comment: Don't forget you're going to have to do this for every version of `operator<<`, e.g. `operator<<(ostream&, const int); operator<<(ostream&, const float); operator<<(ostream&, const char*); ostream<<(ostream&, const std::string&)` etc

Comment: @kfsone Yep you are right!  Is there any better alternative you could suggest?

Comment: That's what I mean, you can't intercept operator<<() as it's defined for multiple standard types, there is no single common symbol for it. You should reimplement/intercept the write functions used by the stdlib implementations of each operator<<()

Comment: not 100% sure,  but on posix compliant systems ostream should call the write() syscall. That's your common symbol used by all implementations.

Comment: @xvan it isn't.  I intercepted the call to printf and tried to do this but it didn't work out well.  Should I post a bounty on this question?

Comment: Yup, can't think of anything else to try.